# Dynamic HTML from SQL

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I am running a query and storing it as a Javascript string that is building dynamic HTML.  How would I insert something into the database that would create a line break that the JS string would read?

Here is how the string is being built:

```
final_string = '<br/><b>' + infoarray[b][3] + '&nbsp;' + convertDate(infoarray[b][1]) + '</b><br/>' + infoarray[b][0] + '<br/>';
```

The 2d infoarray is data that is being pulled from the database.  In the above example, `infoarray[b][3]` is:

1. Call 1-877-968-7762 to initiate your retirement.
2. Make Pension election/return form.
3. Review Savings/401(k) Options.
4. View Medical Options. 5) Review/Confirm beneficiaries.

I want to have a line break before each number and I can't figure out how to do this.  Does anyone know how?

Comment: Don't you already have `<br/>` as the newline, in your string. Do you want `\n` instead.

Comment: I want line breaks in between the message (where the numbers are)..The line breaks I have come after the entire message...

Comment: Where is the code that sets `infoarray[b][3]`?  This is where you should be adding line breaks.  If you must do this after the fact in SQL, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: The code that sets this is in a jaavascript function.

Comment: Basically, I just need to know what to put into the sql info to create a line break..

Comment: If you want line breaks in your HTML then you should replace every newline with <br>. `infoarray[b][3].replace('\n','<br>');`

Comment: Forget the javascript.  If I have '1) Call 1-877-968-7762 to initiate your retirement.  2) Make Pension election/return form.  
3) Review Savings/401(k) Options.  4) View Medical Options.  5) Review/Confirm beneficiaries.' stored in the database how do I put line breaks in this message when it is being pulled from the db..